# IIS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header only on image uploading on ASP.NET 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, cors

I currently have a VueJS frontend server where I make ajax requests using axios to my ASP.NET 3.1 backend API. When starting my project in **debug or release** in Visual studio, my form correctly works. The problem occurs **only** when publishing my web API on IIS. I've got a CORS Policy allow anything basically in my Web API's startup.

**Cors Policy under Startup#ConfigureServices**

```cs
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            });
```

**Enabling my policy under Startup#Configure**

```cs
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Here is my `axios` request :

```js
let data = new FormData()
if(this.file !== null)
  data.append("Icons", this.file.file, this.file.file.name)

data.append('Id', this.itemId)
// append other data...

axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.$store.state.token
axios.post(this.$store.state.api + 'items/edit', data).then(() => {
  console.log('success')
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

The request is successful when no image is provided in the `FormData`. However, when an image is sent, it returns an error :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://exemple.com:5001/api/items/edit' from origin 'http://exemple.com has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**This error only occurs when my application is published on IIS (6.2)**

Comment: Download, install, and configure IIS CORS module please, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference

Comment: As lex says, you should install the cors module, you could follow below steps to enable the cors header. 1.Open Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager.
2.Right click the site you want to enable CORS for and go to Properties.
3.Change to the HTTP Headers tab.
4.In the Custom HTTP headers section, click Add.
5.Enter Access-Control-Allow-Origin as the header name.
Enter * as the header value.
Click Ok twice.

Comment: I don't see "Properties" under the site. However, I've tried adding CORS manually in my web.config but now whatever request i'm doing to the web api, it says that I'm using multiple cors values (I'm guessing it's caused I've configured it inside my code, and in the web.config).

Comment: I was using the wrong configuration. It now works, but now I've got a 500 Internal Error. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the comments by [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li) and [Brando Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7609093/brando-zhang), I added a CORS configuration to my `web.config` of the Web API project.

CORS Configuration :

```
<cors enabled="true">
  <add origin="*" >
      <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
  </add>
</cors>
```

Comment: Which section of web.config does it need adding to?